# Imagemagick & 3Drotate

Tags: imagemagick

I recently had to move my site from one server to another and it appears [Fred's 3Drotate script](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/3Drotate/index.php) creates files that have Imagemagick settings in them instead of image data.  When I first ran the script I received the following error:

```
expr: warning: unportable BRE: `^[0-9][0-9]*$': using `^' as the first character of the basic regular expression is not portable; it is being ignored
expr: warning: unportable BRE: `^[+-][0-9][0-9]*$': using `^' as the first character of the basic regular expression is not portable; it is being ignored
expr: warning: unportable BRE: `^[0-9]*[\\.][0-9]*$': using `^' as the first character of the basic regular expression is not portable; it is being ignored
expr: warning: unportable BRE: `^[+-][0-9]*[\\.][0-9]*$': using `^' as the first character of the basic regular expression is not portable; it is being ignored
```

I was able to resolve this by removing each instance of the '^' character.  The script runs and it creates a file of a few hundred KB, but the contents appear to be a configuration such as:

```
id=MagickCache
quantum-depth=16
class=DirectClass  colors=0  matte=False
columns=500  rows=500 depth=8
colorspace=sRGB
compression=JPEG  quality=75
units=PixelsPerInch
resolution=72x72
page=500x500+0+0
rendering-intent=Perceptual
gamma=0.454545
red-primary=0.64,0.33  green-primary=0.3,0.6  blue-primary=0.15,0.06
white-point=0.3127,0.329
date:create=2012-08-10T20:44:21-07:00
date:modify=2012-08-10T20:44:21-07:00
jpeg:colorspace=2
jpeg:sampling-factor=2x2,1x1,1x1
```

Any ideas?  I'm running imagemagick version 6.7.8-9 which is newer than what was on my original server<strike>, however I don't know which version that was</strike>.

**Update:**
I'm on a CentOS box using 3DRotate revised by Fred on 3/11/10. ImageMagick is version 6.7.8-9 whereas my old server, also CentOS was using version 6.7.6-0.

Comment: You surely know which Operating System your old, and which your new server runs on?!?

Comment: So you change the script without understanding what the effects of your changes are and then you complain that it *'creates files that have Imagemagick settings in them instead of image data'* ?!? :-)

Answer (score 0):

[**Fred's 3Drotate script**](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/3Drotate/index.php) still works fine for me. I have no reason to complain.

This is on Mac OS X Lion, with Bash version `GNU bash, Version 4.2.37(2)-release`....

You are strongly advised to re-download the script and try again. If you want to report a bug, you should give info about your OS, your Bash and your ImageMagick versions...

Oh, and [***see also this page***](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php), which states...

- ...you need ImageMagick v6.3.5.0 or higher for the script to work,
- ...gives some hints about troubleshooting and
- ...tells you the eMail address of the author so you can contact him to discuss your problems.

Answer (score 0):

With recent changes to ImageMagick between IM 6.7.6.7 and IM 6.7.8.3 for colorspace changes and grayscale becoming linear, I have had to go through recently all my scripts and make appropriate changes. I am only part way through my scripts as of this date, but have fixed about 1/3 to 1/2, but 3Drotate did not need any changes since the last one on 11/26/2011. But your version is to old, so you will need to get an update. The problems you seem to have may or may not be related. But appear to be related to the unix utility expr. I would make sure that you have a current version of that installed. The following works perfectly fine for me on both IM 6.7.6.0 and 6.7.8.9 on my Mac OSX Snow Leopard

3Drotate pan=45 tilt=45 auto=zc mandril.jpg mandril_test.jpg

The first question I would ask is what was your exact command line. As you can see the arguments are a bit different from my other scripts as they include equal signs.

If you still have trouble, report them to me or on the ImageMagick Discourse forum at http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=1

Fred

Comment: Thanks Fred.  I didn't make the connection.  I just emailed you about this.  I'm going to look into expr to see what I can find.  It turns out my old server which was once working, is no longer working even though neither 3Drotate nor IM have been updated.  I'm thinking it's more of an OS issue.